# Why do array element values not change?

Tags: arrays, c

```
int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[9 - i];
    a[9 - i] = tmp;
}

for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    printf("%d", a[i]);
}
```

The result of it is: 1234567890,
but why not 10987654321
since it switch values in the first for loop,
but why can not change it when the next for loop runs

I have tried to move "int tmp" outside of the loop, but of no use at all.

Comment: Draw out the array at each step on paper.

Comment: Edited C++ tag to C tag because this is clearly C code, even if it is being compiled with a C+ compiler.

Comment: This is the perfect time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Pay close attentoion to the array indexes you use (`i` and `9 - i`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<=9;i++){
    int tmp= a[i];
    a[i] = a[9-i];
    a[9-i] = tmp;
}
```

Each iteration it swaps elements.

On the first iteration, it swaps `a[0]` and `a[9]`. On the second `a[1]` and `a[8]` and so on.

But what about the 10th iteration?

Well, it swaps `a[9]` and `a[0]`. But you already swapped those, so it's just swapping them *back* the way they were.

If you stop after 5 iterations, so you're only swapping each pair once, your code will behave the way you expect.

---

To illustrate the suggestion from @user4581301 in comments, see below. We get `begin` and `end` pointers to the first and last elements in the array, respectively. Our loop continues as long as the `begin` pointer is less than the `end` pointer. If `end` is greater than `begin` it means we've gone past halfway. If they're equal, it means our array had an odd number of elements, and we've hit the middle one. That middle element wouldn't need to be swapped, so either way we're done.

The update in the loop increments `begin` and decrements `end`, moving inward one place from each end of the array.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    int *begin, *end;

    for (begin = &arr[0], end = &arr[9]; begin < end; ++begin, --end) {
        int temp = *begin;
        *begin = *end;
        *end = temp;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: When writing something like this I'll use a begin pointer and an end pointer (or begin and end indices) and at the end of each iteration of the loop I advance begin and decrease the end. When end <= begin, you've hit the middle and stop.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are swapping every pair twice.

Iterate it to half of the array. If you are not able to spot the error kindly dry run it on paper, you will get the answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[9 - i];
        a[9 - i] = tmp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, but a good answer generally has some meat, explanation and possibly a solution, on its bones.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).